# Vim won't save backup files into the correct directory

Tags: vim

I have a vimrc file that has the following (along with a lot of other settings):

```
set backupdir=~/.vim-tmp
```

However, when I open a file `foobar.txt` using vim, change some text, save it and exit vim, a `.footbar.txt~` file is left behind in the same directory as foobar.  A few questions:

1) Shouldn't my setting in vimrc force this backup file to go into ~/.vim-tmp rather than the current directory?
2) Shouldn't the backup file be deleted when vim exits?

And just to verify, I searched for "backup" in my vimrc and only got the result at the top of the screen.  Therefore, I don't think my setting is being overridden.

Comment: do you have `~/.vim-tmp` directory?

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that

Comment: Try set `directory=~/.vim-tmp` as well as I was having similar trouble until I added that. I assume the permissions on `~/.vim-tmp` are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured my problem out on my own.  What happened was my vimrc had `set undofile` however it did not have an undo directory; therefore, adding the following solved my issued:

```
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
```